# Cannot install package (python-twisted) because mismatching python version

Tags: python

This Error almost drove me mad !

While installing twisted ,an error show out and that's what my terminal told me:

```
Processing Dependency: python = 2.6.6-64.el6 for package: tkinter-    2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: tkinter-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (rhel)
       Requires: python = 2.6.6-64.el6
       Installed: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
           python = 2.6.6-66.el6_8
       Available: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (rhel)
           python = 2.6.6-64.el6
```

and when I ls my stuff in  /usr/bin ,it shows:

```
[root@dhcp-128-69 bin]# ls -l python*
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 9032 Aug  9 18:12 python
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    6 Nov 23 14:35 python2 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 9032 Aug  9 18:12 python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1418 Aug  9 18:12 python2.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   16 Nov 23 14:38 python-config -> python2.6-config
```

as addition:

```
[root@dhcp-128-69 bin]# python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

so HOW can I available my python-2.6.6-64?

Or any way that can make me install successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to install the package are as follows :

1. Install python any version .
2. Then, Install the appropriate exe

   http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

   Twisted 10.1.0 for Python 2.6 ( msi |  exe) or Twisted 10.1.0 for Python 2.5 ( msi |  exe)
3. download the zope interface .

   http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads
4. Install setuptools

   http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads

   Update the PATH variable to the subdirectory containing easy_install.exe .
5. install zope interface using :

   `easy_install zope.interface-3.6.1-py2.5-win32.egg`

Comment: Sorry I was a little bit confused .Emmm why exe & win32? I'm using RHEL6.8 in fact.